# Are you open to a new project? or Are you open for a new project?

Tags: grammar

These two statements seem correct, but actually, which one is the proper statement? And can you explain how the usage of to & for changes the meaning of the statement?

Hey, are you open to a new project?

or

Hey, Are you open for a new project?

Answer (score 1):

1

> Hey, are you open to a new project?

2

> Hey, are you open for a new project?

In this context, we should use your example (1), with *open to*.

*open to* means **willing to consider** as shown in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/open), definition C1 for *open*.

> I'd like to think I'm open to (= willing to consider) any reasonable suggestion.

*for* is found in an example under another definition for *open*, meaning not decided.

> We can leave our offer open for another week, but we have to have your decision by then.

This definition is not applicable to your example.

Edit:
[open for](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/open%20for%20%28someone%29) is an idiom, which means

> to perform before (the main performer at a concert, show, etc.)

That definition is also not applicable to your example.

Comment: open to = willing to consider & open for = ???

Comment: @Rajendran Nadar, I have added more details to my answer.